# Switch Rule With Multiple Statments

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement

How can I use switch rule with multiple statements? For ex. convert this:

```
switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                ans = inchesToCentimeters(num);
                System.out.println(ans);
                break;
        }
```

To something like this (I don't know how to do it obviously but this is just a guess):

```
switch (choice) {
            case 1 -> ans = inchesToCentimeters(num);
                   -> System.out.println(ans);
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with your first snippet? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just change it to switch rule. There isn't anything wrong with it but NetBeans is telling me to change it to switch rule.

Comment: Use just `System.out.println(inchesToCentimeters(num))`?

Comment: This is for school. This isn't the most efficient code but I have to specifically use methods that use double instead of void. So I have to return it to a value in my main code. I was just wondering if there's a way to put multiple lines of code inside a switch rule.

Comment: I posted the full code btw. In case you were wondering.

Comment: You shouldn't post it as an answer. Add whatever you want by editing your question

Comment: Ah well. I'll keep that in mind. Someone answered it so it's all good. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JDK 12 should be changed like this:

```java
switch (choice) {
    case 1 -> {
        ans = inchesToCentimeters(num);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    case 2 -> {
        // next case
    }
}
```

Also, you could return result from `switch` and fix duplicated code:

```java
double ans = switch(choice) {
    case 1 -> inchesToCentimeters(num);
    case 2 -> centimetersToInches(num);
    case 3 -> feetToCentimeters(num);
    case 4 -> centimetersToFeet(num);
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad choice: " + choice);
};

System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: OH. Thank you. That's great.